# Querying Binary Field In MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to query a binary field in mongo db. The data looks like this:

```
{"_id":"WE8fSixi8EuWnUiThhZdlw=="}
```

[image]

I've tried a lot of things for example:

```
{ '_id': new Binary( 'WE8fSixi8EuWnUiThhZdlw==', Binary.SUBTYPE_DEFAULT) }
{ '_id': Binary( 'WE8fSixi8EuWnUiThhZdlw==', 0) }
```

etc

Nothing seems to be working, have exhausted google and the mongo documentation, any helper would be amazing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

Now you should be able to query UUID and BinData from MongoDB Compass v1.20+ ([COMPASS-1083](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-1083)). For example: `{"field": BinData(0, "valid_base64")}`.

**PREVIOUS:**

I see that you're using [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) to query the field. Unfortunately, the current version of MongoDB Compass (v1.16.x) does not support querying binary data.

You can utilise [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) to query the data instead. For example:

```
db.collection.find({'_id':BinData(0, "WE8fSixi8EuWnUiThhZdlw==")});
```

Please note that the field name `_id` is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be *unique* in the collection, and  is immutable. Depending on the value of the binary that you're storing into `_id`, I would suggest to store the binary in another field and keep the value of `_id` to contain [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid).

Comment: Thanks I managed to get it working by changing too to Robo 3T. This allowed me to query with binary. Thanks for your help.